# Xaml Border issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am using `HeaderedContentControl` for displaying my label & text box as below..

```
<Style x:Key="ContentBorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="HeaderedContentControl" x:Key="BaseLabeledItemStyle">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="HeaderedContentControl">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border Grid.Column="0">
                                <ContentPresenter Name="header"        
                                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="1"
                                    Style="{StaticResource ContentBorderStyle}">
                                <AdornerDecorator>
                                    <ContentPresenter Name="content"                                         
                                                  Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Content}"/>
                                </AdornerDecorator>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
  </Style>

<HeaderedContentControl
                Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BaseLabeledItemStyle}" 
                Header="Emp Name">
                <!--<ContentControl>-->
                <TextBox x:Name="txtName" 
                         Text="{Binding Path=EmpName, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
            </HeaderedContentControl>
```

As I am using Border brush as "Blue" for content control My content Control is always displaying with Blue border. When there is an validation error, my text box which I am using inside Headered content control's border is changing to red as I am using ValidationOnDataerror. now my requirement is to change even the content border too in Red Color when Validation occurs (i.e. when inner text box is in red color)...

I am attaching an Image how my control is populating.. in that (1) is border of my content control & (2) is my text box control.

How can I change the color of content control based on Text box color...

thanks in advance...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `DataTrigger` for additional highlighting

```
<Style x:Key="ContentBorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding (Validation.HasError), ElementName=txtName}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>                    
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**FYI:**
If you want to show the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` on any other control than `TextBox` use [Validation.ValidationAdornerSiteFor Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.validationadornersitefor.aspx). e.g.

```
<HeaderedContentControl Validation.ValidationAdornerSiteFor="{Binding ElementName=txtName}"
```

or

```
<Style x:Key="ContentBorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
    <Setter Property="Validation.ValidationAdornerSiteFor" Value="{Binding ElementName=txtName}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I am using this style for multiple controls, I should not use "txtName".. Could you please help me how can I replace "txtName" with my respective textbox?

Comment: and here I am not only using textbox but also using it with different controls like Date time control & Combobox...